# Div on other div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<div id="one">aaa</div>
<div id="two">bbbbbbbbbb</div>
<span id="click">click</span>
```

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/g6Myb/

how can i get #two and put him on #one with jQuery after click span#click?

```
<div id="one">aaa</div>
<div id="two">bbbbbbbbbb</div>
<span id="click">click</span>
```

```
#one {width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: red}
#two {width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: green; opacity: 0.3 }
```

```
$('.click').click(function(){})  // what to do here ?
```

Comment: Come on ... you havn't even tried to figure this out for yourself.

Comment: What do you mean put him on #one? Do you want them to have the same position?

Comment: @ryadavilli yes, with opacity

Comment: hey... http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is about a million different ways of doing it, the one I chose is to wrap `#one` and `#two` with relatively positioned `div` and move `#two` to 0X0 on click

updated your fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/g6Myb/1/

```
#one {width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: red}
#two {width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: green; opacity: 0.3 }
#wrapper{position: relative;}
#two.on{position: absolute; top:0; left:0;}
```

```
$('#click').click(function(){
    $("#two").addClass("on");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You're targeting a class instead an ID

```
$('.click').click(function(){});
   ^----- USE #
```

than you can use this methods:

http://api.jquery.com/append/
http://api.jquery.com/appendto/

Examples:

```
$('#click').click(function(){
    $('#one').append( $('#two') );
});

$('#click').click(function(){
    $('#two').appendTo( $('#one') );
});
```

If your elements contain text those might not be the desired methods you want...

so if you desire to **OVERLAY** `#two` over `#one` than you can go with `offset`:

<kbd>**[jsBin demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g6Myb/2/)**</kbd>

```
$('#click').click(function(){
    var TWOpos = $('#one').offset();
    var pos = {X: TWOpos.left, Y:TWOpos.top };
    $('#two').css({position:'absolute', left:pos.X, top:pos.Y });
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/offset/

**DOCS:** http://api.jquery.com/ (read it always. those are your tools!)

Comment: @Ark really?! hahahahaahah :D Here for everyone! https://www.google.hr/search?q=steve+carell&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb

Answer (score 0):

You will want to make a new CSS class:

```
.hoverOpacity{
  position:absolute;
  top: 0; //or wherever you want to put it
  right: 0;  //or whereever you want to put it
  opacity: .5; //plus all the browser specific
}
```

Then on click, add this class to the div:

```
$('#click').click(function(){
   $('#two').addClass('hoverOpacity');
});
```

Comment: Greatly appreciated.  I was getting confused by that one.